# Transform relational database list into Python list

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am new to both Python and SQLite and I am trying to learn 
how to transform a list (of exam scores) stored in a relational 
database into a python list[sub-list].  Given the information 
below, how can I achieve this.

#### Schema

```sql
Exam(id, t_date, name)
Result(id, exam_id, score)
```

#### Table Data

```sql
INSERT INTO Exam VALUES(1, '2014-01-31', 'Sql Fundamentals')
INSERT INTO Result VALUES(1, 1, 87)
INSERT INTO Result VALUES(2, 1, 65)
INSERT INTO Result VALUES(3, 1, 98)
```

#### Query

```sql
SELECT 
   E.id, E.t_date, E.[name], R.score
FROM 
   Exam AS E INNER JOIN Result AS R 
ON 
   E.ID = R.exam_id
```

#### Query results

```sql
1, '2014-01-31', 'Sql Fundamentals', 87
1, '2014-01-31', 'Sql Fundamentals', 65
1, '2014-01-31', 'Sql Fundamentals', 98
```

#### Desired results

```python
[1, '2014-01-31', 'Sql Fundamentals', [87, 65, 98]]
```

Comment: If you order your query by e.id, you can use your application code to rearrange the results.  I am not a python programmer, but this is a simple task in c#.  It's even simpler in ColdFusion.

Comment: Thanks Dan for responding.  I know how to achieve my goal with application code (VB).  I do not know how to achieve the goal with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite returns queries as lists of tuples. In that case, you could do:

```
>>> test = [(1, '2014-01-31', 'Sql Fundamentals', 87), (1, '2014-01-31', 'Sql Fundamentals', 65), (1, '2014-01-31', 'Sql Fundamentals', 98)]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> final = defaultdict(list)
>>> for elem in test:
        final[elem[:3]].append(elem[-1])


>>> final
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {(1, '2014-01-31', 'Sql Fundamentals'): [87, 65, 98]})
>>> final[(1, '2014-01-31', 'Sql Fundamentals')]
[87, 65, 98]
```

Comment: Thanks Sukrit!  Using your example, I was able to create the desired results.